# force GAM intercept in r

Tags: r, mgcv

I have a GAM

```
require(mgcv)

data =
   pct_remain week
1    94.69388    2
2    94.69388    2
3    94.69388    2
4    94.69388    2
5    94.69388    2
6    94.69388    2
7    86.80272    2
8    88.38095    2
9    86.45963    2
10   84.17234    2
11   84.17234    2
12   81.63265    2
13   71.51020    4
14   64.24745    4
15   55.48205    4
16   82.76644    4
17   89.38776    4
18   79.45578    4
19   75.63579    4
20   81.93878    4
21   85.50133    4
22   84.12965    4
23   86.07710    4
24   89.38776    4
25   89.38776    6
26   89.38776    6
27   89.38776    6
28   79.81050    6
29   80.44898    6
30  101.30612    6
31   89.38776    6
32  134.08163    6
33   89.38776    6
34   75.63579    6
35   83.22308    6
36   72.62755    6
37   89.38776    8
38  104.28571    8
39   81.93878    8
40   71.51020    8
41   70.89374    8
42   70.89374    8
43   74.48980    8
44   74.48980    8
45   70.76531    8
46   46.83673   12
47   47.28111   12
48   60.00000   12
49   82.23673    8
50   70.23324    8
51   71.51020    8
52   85.94976    4
53   86.07710    4
54   85.94976    4
55   84.27988    4
56   86.50428    4
57   86.75870    4
58   70.98439    8
59   74.48980    8
60   78.87155    8
61   68.57143   12
62   68.87755   12
63   63.36735   12
64   83.80102    4
65   83.80102    4
66   89.38776    4
67   68.75981    8
68   77.46939    8
69   71.51020    8
70   51.42857   12
71   44.79263   12
72   65.27473   12
73   83.94958   16
74   68.57143   16
75   52.18487   16
76   47.47253   16
77   59.14286   16
78   55.44643   16


gam_mod_k3 <- gam(pct_remain ~ s(week, k = 5),data=data)
```

It is generally very close to what I want, except I know the y-intercept...it should be 100. As written, when I look at the output it does not make sense because the intercept is ~80, but at week 0, I should have 100% of the dependent variable...

How can I force the y-intercept through 100 for a gam?

Comment: In a GAM fitted in mgcv, the intercept is the mean of the response, it's not what the covariates are all 0